# using animation when menu becomes sticky

Tags: jquery, css

I wrote a `fixed` class to make a sticky menu.

css :

```
#categories.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

jquery (to add `fixed` class when user scroll down) :

```
if ($('body').hasClass('sticky-header')) {
    var theLoc = $('#categories').position().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (theLoc >= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            if ($('#categories').hasClass('fixed')) {
                $('#categories').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        } else {
            if (!$('#categories').hasClass('fixed')) {
                $('#categories').addClass('fixed');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

but when my menu be sticky, it done happen very suddenly. now I want to change the current location to top-left side with an animation.

Comment: A demo would be useful but you have to animate to and from something...and you aren't as yet.

Comment: for example, http://www.shadyab.com  this site is what I want to do.

Comment: Links to existing sites aren't really helpful. A brief *minimal* demo of *your* code would be.

Comment: Instead of that big if/else why not use `$('#categories').toggleClass('fixed', !(theLoc >= $(window).scrollTop()))` or similar if the logic is wrong (I wasn't thorough)?